# Browser constant TLS errors

Tags: windows, networking, browser, ssl

Sometimes when browsing a site, normally after clicking a link after it's already loading, I start seeing some type of TLS error. It presents itself in different browser as following:

- *Chrome*: `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`
- *Edge*: Can’t connect securely to this
  page
- *Firefox*: `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`
- *IE*: `INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`

After that it doesn't load the site at all anymore. This issue mostly persists through restarts and in some cases I've been unable to visit websites for months, like the English language Wikipedia (DnDBeyond is another example).

Other symptom of the same problem is some requests being refused. StackOverflow stylesheet request fail with a `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` error (as seen through Chrome developer tools), for example.

I initially though it might have had something to do with my Windows certificate chains, but for what I gather online Firefox uses its own to do the TLS verification.

Trying to restart into security mode made all the sites work flawlessly, so it must have something to do with some program or service that is started with the machine but only my audio driver is even enable in the Task Manager startup tab.

One that seemed to work was `ipconfig /flushdns` and `netsh winsock reset` followed by a restart but even then, it just works until I misclick something and then all the sites stop working (if I open Wikipedia, StackOverflow css stops working; if I get an error in DnDBeyond, Wikipedia stops working;).

Comment: Best way we can help you requires knowing what certificate you receive when you go to Wikipedia

Comment: It is likely some middleware in your network either deliberately meddling with the traffic (i.e. firewall, IDS) or accidentally (like a buggy router similar to what was described for [Telekom Speedport (German)](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Firewall-Probleme-bei-der-Telekom-Speedport-Router-blockieren-Onleihe-4669660.html)).

Comment: @Ramhound how can I provide this?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if I say that this problem doesn't happens when using my phone in the same network does it helps?

Comment: How you view the certificate for a website slightly differs between browsers.